# Add a button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a questionnaire that asks questions then has a button at the end of the page called "display answers" which will show the user which answers they got correct.

If I were to use this question for example:

```
<p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>                   
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>       
</ul>
```

How would I go about creating a button for this code that when pressed, tells if the answer is correct or not?

Comment: have you tried anything? its going to be something like: <button onclick=yourFunction()> Display Answers </button>

Comment: FYI - You've probably been downvoted because you come across as not trying anything prior to submitting the question (Provide examples of what you've already tried). fruitoftheloins has provided a great answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Two `.addEventListeners()`

  - One on the container that holds all of the questions and answers (e.g. `#QA1`)
  - The other on the button used when finished with the quiz (e.g. `#btn1`)
- When the user picks an answer, `#QA1` will listen for any clicks on any radio button (e.g. `.answers`). Using a single event listener for multiple `event.targets` (i.e. the element clicked) is far more efficient than adding one on each radio button. Through comparing what was actually clicked (radio button) and what was the element with the listener, we'll can get the radio button's id. See this [article for details](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm).
- Once the id of the clicked radio button is determined (see previous reference), it's pushed to an array (e.g. `answers[]`).
- When the user is done, he/she clicks the "DONE" button, triggering the click event of `#btn1`.

  - A `for` loop is used to iterate over the `answer[]` and `key[]` arrays. On each iteration (i.e.loop,) the two are compared for matching elements.
  - The results are printed on `#out1` which is an `<output>` element nested in an ordered list (`<ol>`).

**Snippet**

```js
var qa = document.getElementById('QA1');
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var answers = [];
var key = ['q1c', 'q2a', 'q3d'];

qa.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target != event.currentTarget) {
    var choice = event.target.id;
    answers.push(choice);
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}, false);

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var qList = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
  var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');

  for (var i = 0; i < qList.length; i++) {
    if (answers[i] === key[i]) {
      out1.innerHTML += '<li>' + answers[i] + ' is correct</li>';
    } else {
      out1.innerHTML += '<li>' + answers[i] + ' is incorrect, the correct answer is ' + key[i] + '</li>';
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.45'Verdana';
}
* {
  font: inherit;
}
.question {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.answers {
  list-style: none;
}
.answers li {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  position: relative;
  top: 2.25px;
}
#btn1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#out1 {
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<ol id="QA1" class="QA">
  <li id="q1" class="question">What is the answer to this question?

    <ol class="answers">

      <li>a.
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a" />
        <label for="q1a">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>b.
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b" />
        <label for="q1b">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>c.
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c" />
        <label for="q1c">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>d.
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d" />
        <label for="q1d">Answer</label>
      </li>

    </ol>
    <!--answers-->

  </li>
  <!--question-->
  <li id="q2" class="question">What is the answer to this question?

    <ol class="answers">

      <li>a.
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a" />
        <label for="q2a">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>b.
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b" />
        <label for="q2b">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>c.
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c" />
        <label for="q2c">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>d.
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d" />
        <label for="q2d">Answer</label>
      </li>

    </ol>
    <!--answers-->

  </li>
  <!--question-->
  <li id="q3" class="question">What is the answer to this question?

    <ol class="answers">

      <li>a.
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a" />
        <label for="q3a">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>b.
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b" />
        <label for="q3b">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>c.
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c" />
        <label for="q3c">Answer</label>
      </li>

      <li>d.
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d" />
        <label for="q3d">Answer</label>
      </li>

    </ol>
    <!--answers-->

  </li>
  <!--question-->

</ol>
<!--QA-->
<button id="btn1"><a href="">DONE</a>
</button>
<ol>
  <output id="out1"></output>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul id="answers" class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>                   
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="showAnswer()" />       
</ul>

<span id="info"></span>
```

Then add a script above that piece of code:

```
<script>
    function showAnswer(){
        if(document.getElementById('q1a').checked){
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "Correct!";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I don't know the answer to your quiz, so answer 1 is correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Questionare</title>
 
</head>
<body>
<p>1. What is the answer to this question?</p>     
  
  <ul onclick="man()">
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a">Answer 1<br/>               <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b">Answer 2<br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c">Answer 3<br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="d">Answer 4<br/>       
  </ul>
  <p id="m"></p>
<script>
  var man = function(){
    document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = 'The correct answer is: Answer 1';
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what u want, done in simplest way, using CSS Document object model, for reference go here [HTML CSS DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)